# MS Access: adding column if not exist (or try/catch it)

Tags: ms-access, alter-table, if-not-exists, exists

this is an easy question, but I can't find out the solution...

I have to check if a column exists and add it if the test is negative. How can I do with only sql code?

This is the syntax for SQL Server:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM   sys.columns 
  WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Person]') 
         AND name = 'ColumnName'
)
BEGIN
    --STUFF HERE
END
```

and for MS Access, using only SQL code... what is the right syntax to do it?

**UPDATE**: also a way to do a try cath statement would be ok, I only need to not add anything if it doesn't exist... so, also a try catch is ok, I think. Also try catch is easily possible to use in sql server... and for access?

**UPDATE 2**: I have done this:

```
If Not Exists (Select Column_Name
           From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           Where Table_Name = 'TabTessereVeicoli'
           And Column_Name = 'TAGA')
begin

    ALTER TABLE TabTessereVeicoli ADD TAGA text(25) NULL;

end
```

but I get the error "*SQL statement not valid. Expected DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT or UPDATE.*" Why? How can I do an alter table after an IF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access doesn't support the `IF EXISTS` syntax in queries; I think your error is coming from that. It's also very difficult to do any sort of procedural logic using Access SQL. Your alternatives are to run the `ALTER TABLE` statement and handle the error elsewhere or use VBA to conditionally run the statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
 tableexist = CheckTableExistance("Tbl_Name");
if (tableexist == true)
{
    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from Tbl_Name", con))
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
    {
        var table = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        var nameCol = table.Columns["ColumnName"];

        if (table.Rows.Count <= Col_Count)
        {
            Connection_State();
            ///Now Alter Table And Add New Coloumn
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("ALTER TABLE Tbl_Name ADD Fld_Name Field_Type", con);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

Comment: This code snippet looks like it might work. Can you explain how it does?